# Asp.net Mvc Web App project doesn't seem to compile code I add to folders I created?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have a Code folder in my asp.net mvc web project, I added a .cs file and the compiler does not seem to pick up any errors I make.  However, if I first add the .cs file to the root of my mvc web project and then moves it to the Code folder, the compiler will work properly.  Why is this happening?  I'm using VS10 and mvc3.  Thanks.

**Edit**: I notice I first called the folder App_Code and then renamed it to Code, so it seems if you add .cs to App_Code the compiler doesn't run on those, even if you move the .cs out or change the folder name to something else. Very strange.

Comment: are you using a source control system?

Comment: how are you using dropbox with your visual studio solution?

Comment: I just added more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describing it sounds like the `Build Action` is not set to `Compile` on your file.

In response to your **Edit**. The `App_Code` is a special folder in ASP.NET, its files are compiled at run time. For more information see: [Shared Code Folders in ASP.NET Web Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response, how do you check if my file's Build Action is set to Compile?  I went to project > Properties > Build, but only saw the Configuration is set to Action(Debug), Platform target: Any CPU

Comment: Locate the file in your `Solution Explorer` then right-click and see `Properties`->`Build Action`